# Simple replacement for Redux in ES6

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, ecmascript-6, callback

The idea about this code is that it's a full replacement of Redux — in 22 lines of code.

```
let state = null
const beforeSetStateCallbacks = []
const afterSetStateCallbacks = []

export const beforeSetState = (fn) => beforeSetStateCallbacks.push(fn)
export const afterSetState = (fn) => afterSetStateCallbacks.push(fn)

export const setState = async (key, value) => {
  if (state === null) state = {}
  // QUESTION: Should I use Promise.all for performance reason?
  // Note that the order might be important though
  for (const fn of beforeSetStateCallbacks) await fn(key, value)
  state[key] = value
  for (const fn of afterSetStateCallbacks) await fn(key, value)
}

export const stateEmpty = () => {
  return !state
}

export const getState = (key) => {
  if (!state) return null
  return state[key]
}
```

There is no `dispatch()` because the whole actions/reducers madness melts away, simple functions are meant to modify the state and then call (for example) `setState('userInfo', userInfo)`.

Example usage is here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lacy-ornament

The rundown:

- `index.html` contains this:

```
<script type="module" src="./one.js"></script>
<my-one></my-one>
```

The first line defines a custom element `my-one`. The second line places that element.

- `StateMixin.js` contains this:

```
import { setState, getState, afterSetState, stateEmpty } from './reducs.js'

export const StateMixin = (base) => {
  return class Base extends base {
    constructor () {
      super()

      if (stateEmpty()) {
        setState('basket', { items: [], total: 0 })
      }

      this.basket = getState('basket')

      afterSetState((k, value) => {
        this[k] = { ...value }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, something is added to the constructor where if the state isn't yet defined, it gets assigned a default initial state.
Then, assigning`this.basket` makes sure that the `basket` property of the element is current, and `afterSetState()` will make sure that further modifications to the basket will also update `this.basket`.

This means that any element that has `this.basket` as a property will get updated when `this.basket` is changed.

- `one.js` contains this:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element/lit-element.js'
import { StateMixin } from './StateMixin.js'
import { addItemToBasket } from './actions.js'

// Extend the LitElement base class
class MyOne extends StateMixin(LitElement) {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      basket: {
        type: Object,
        attribute: false
      }
    }
  }
  render () {
    return html`
      <p>Basket</p>
      <p>Total items: ${this.basket.total}</p>
      <p>Items:</p>
      <ul>
        ${this.basket.items.map(item => html`
          <li>${item.description}</li> 
        `)}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" id="description">
      <button @click="${this._addItem}">Add</button>
    `
  }
  _addItem () {    
    const inputField = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#description')
    addItemToBasket( { description: inputField.value })
    inputField.value = ''
  }
}
// Register the new element with the browser.
customElements.define('my-one', MyOne)
```

This is a very minimalistic element, where a few interesting things happen. First of all, it's mixed with `StateMixin.js`, which will ensure that the constructor deals with status and registration for changes. It also defines a `basket` property, which means that when the basket is changed, the element will re-render.

Finally, `_addItem()` will run the action `addItemToBasket()` which is the only action defined.

- `actions.js` contains this:

```
import { getState, setState } from './reducs.js'
export const addItemToBasket = (item) => {
  const basket = getState('basket')

   basket.items. push(item)
   basket.total = basket.items.length
   basket.items = [ ...basket.items ]

   setState('basket', basket)
}
```

This is simple: first of all, the state is loaded with `getState()`. Then, it's modified. Note that lit-html only re-renders changed things. So, basket.items is re-assigned. Finally, the state is set with `setState()`.

Note: you might have multiple branches in your state: `basket`, `userInfo`, `appConfig`, and so on.

Questions:

- If I use `Promise.all`, I will lose the certainty that the calls are called in order. Do you think I should still do it?
- Is there a way to prevent the check on state every single time in `setState()` and `stateEmpty()`?  The idea is that stateEmpty() returns false if the state has never been initialised.
- How would you recommend to implement an "unlisten" function here? As in, what's the simplest possible path to provide the ability to stop listening?
- Since this is indeed a working 100% replacement on Redux (in 22 lines), shall I name the functions more ala Redux? Redux has "subscribe", but I like giving the option to subscribe to before and after the change. Maybe `subscribe()` and `subscribeBefore()`?

Comment: @Merc, please add a testable https://jsfiddle.net/ link (or alike) with code (and sample object)

Comment: OK doing it now

Comment: OK done. @RomanPerekhrest doing this was a JOB AND A HALF :D I hope what I wrote makes sense. I really do look (humbly) forward to comments and reviews.

Comment: I just saw the tag "reinventing-the-wheel". I think we should also add the tag "simplifying-an-overcomplex-wheel" :D

Comment: I am not a redux user so my knowledge is limited. However I have some questions? There is no state history?, The sate is being mutated and holding references, not copies. Are you relying on the components to ensure only copies are passed and that the callbacks do not mutate the state value? The callbacks (Before, and After) are state global, this seams very clumbersum for large states models. Is the need to be 22 lines forcing the code using your mini redux to be longer?

Comment: 1) Redux doesn't have any state history either 2) Mutation (or not) is always possible in Javascript, Redux or Reducs can't stop code from doing so. 2a) I returned a copu of the object in my example because lit-element requires it. Some frameworks won't need you to do that 3) Callbacks are not state global, they are called for the right branch of the state (basket, userInfo, appconfig) 4) The code that uses Redux is normally wwaaaaaayyyyyy longer with all those reducers, actions, and amazing code bureaucracy.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: No problem. I am a CodeReview newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may or may not have seen a certain movie in the cinema, but the Batman in me wants to say this:

[image]

Not to mention that semicolons don't hurt either.

Also, per @Blindman67, it seems that you are pushing complexity down to the callers. It seems to me a number of callbacks would only want to run for a given `key`, forcing callers to check the `key` value is not good design.

For this part:

> Is there a way to prevent the check on state every single time in
>   setState() and stateEmpty()?

I would declare `state` like `let state = {};`
Then you dont need to check in `setState`, because `state` is already an `Object`.
You would write `stateEmpty` like this:

```
export const stateEmpty = () => {
  return !Object.keys(state).length;
}

export const getState = (key) => {
  return state[key]
}
```

This would save you 2 lines, and avoids the akward `null` value.

The Joker in me considers your `beforeSetStateCallbacks` and `afterSetStateCallbacks` as just two parts of the same coin. I have not tested this, but the below should be both possible and cleaner;

```
let state = {};
const batch = [(key,value)=>state[key] = value];

export const beforeSetState = (fn) => batch.unshift(fn);
export const afterSetState = (fn) => batch.push(fn);


export const setState = async (key, value) => {
  for (const f of batch){
    await f(key, value);
  }
}
```

In this vein, this question becomes easier:

> How would you recommend to implement an "unlisten" function here?

If the subscriber remembers the function they used to subscribe you could go like this, because now you dont care whether the caller listens to before or after.

```
export const unhook = (fn) => batch.splice(0, batch.length, ...batch.filter(f=>f!=fn));
```

The last item I want to mention is a [graceful exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_exit). Your code is short, because for one thing you trust that the caller will always provide a function for `fn`. Consider adding more type checks, otherwise the stack-trace will end frequently in your code.

Comment: GOLDEN. I will implement every single suggestion here. Now... how do I do this? I don't want to change the question. Shall I add the updated code as a trailing update? Sorry, I am a StackOverflow guy, I don't spend enough time here at CodeReview!

Comment: I love your suggestion for batched callback, and how it starts with one prefefined call in the middle. My only problem here is that developers will expect `beforeSetState()` calls to be run in the order they are defined, whereas with your code they will be run in reversed order. Right?

Comment: @Merc after your question has been answered you should NOT change your question!

Comment: About unlistening, a user could want to listen to the same function twice, and only desire to "unlisten" to a specific one. Redux does it by making sure that register() returns a function that will remove that registration. But... I am having trouble finding a nice, reliable way to implement that

Comment: I need to think on the order and unhook points, they are both valid.

Comment: I added the version with all mods applied. I think it's magical!

Comment: In that case, feel free to hit the green checkmark next to the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

After @konjin's great answer, I ended up with this wonderful code:

```
const state = {}
let beforeCallbacks = []
let afterCallbacks = []
let globalId = 0

const deleteId = (id, type) => {
  type === 'a'
    ? afterCallbacks = afterCallbacks.filter(e => e.id !== id)
    : beforeCallbacks = beforeCallbacks.filter(e => e.id !== id)
}

export const register = (fn, type = 'a') => {
  const id = globalId++
  (type === 'a' ? afterCallbacks : beforeCallbacks).push({ fn, id })
  return () => deleteId(id, type)
}

export const setState = async (key, value) => {
  for (const e of [...beforeCallbacks, { fn: () => { state[key] = value } }, ...afterCallbacks]) {
    const v = e.fn(key, value)
    if (v instanceof Promise) await v
  }
}
export const stateEmpty = () => !Object.keys(state).length
export const getState = (key) => state[key]
```

I used his idea in `setState()` to create an array where `state[key] = value` is sandwiched between the before and after calls.

I followed his advice  of assigning `{}` to state, and adding curly brackets like Batman said :D

I implemented de-registration by adding an ID to each one, rather than deleting the function, as I want to make sure I can assign the same function and de-register it without side effects.

His answer IS the accepted answer.

Thanks!